# how to make .in file as input for python

Tags: python, input

here is my code

```
def jumlah(A,B,C):
    global result
    result = A+B+C

count = 0

i = eval(input('input total test case: '))

while count < i :
    A = eval(input('input A: '))
    B = eval(input('input B: '))
    C = eval(input('input C: '))
    jumlah(A,B,C)
    count = count + 1
    print('case no'+str(count)+' : '+str(result))
```

how to put external file for input, so i can do test without entering the number 1 by 1

here is my example input.in file

```
2
1
2
3
2
3
4
```

the first line is total number of case, and the rest is input for A,B and C. my expected result will be

```
case no1 : 6
case no2 : 9
```

please help. thanks

Comment: you should not be evaling user input as a general rule of thumb

Comment: i want to convert my input as int, im just searching around and found eval(input()), do you know how to do that without evaling?thanks

Comment: Use `int(input(...))`.

Comment: int(input(...)) is not working, it return error
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break out your code into individual functions that perform the actions you want to take.  In this case, you can prompt the user if they want to read from a file or input by hand.  Based on that decision you can call the appropriate function.

```
def jumlah(A,B,C):
    result = A+B+C
    return result

def start():
    option = input(' Would you like to: \n'
        ' - (r) read from a file \n'
        ' - (i) input(i) by hand \n' 
        ' - (q) quit \n ')
    if option.lower() not in 'riq':
        print('Invalid choice, please select r, i, or q.')
        option = start()
    return option.lower()

def by_hand():
    count = 0
    i = eval(input('input total test case: '))

    while count < i :
        A = eval(input('input A: '))
        B = eval(input('input B: '))
        C = eval(input('input C: '))
        result = jumlah(A,B,C)
        count = count + 1
        print('case no'+str(count)+' : '+str(result))

def from_file():
    path = input('Please input the path to the file: ')
    with open(path, 'r') as fp:
        cases = int(fp.readline().strip())
        for i in range(1, cases+1):
            a,b,c = fp.readline(), fp.readline(), fp.readline()
            result = jumlah(A,B,C)
            print('case no'+str(i)+' : '+str(result))

def main():
    while True:
        opt = start()
        if opt == 'r':
            from_file()
        if opt == 'i':
            by_hand()
        if opt == 'q':
            print('Goodbye.')
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: woaaah thats actually work, thanks a lot. really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ python my_file.py < my_input.txt
```

I think would do it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the input file and read it,

```
with open("input.in", "r") as inputs:
    for line in ins:
        #your inputs one by one.
```

Comment: the first line should be total number of case, so it should not included in function.